# How to close html tags by a script?

Tags: javascript, html

I think this should be very simple to achieve, but I don’t know where I should search for.

What I want is the following. I have a script that will search for the strings [gallery]. When [gallery] is find, it will replace the tag with an image. This I have achieved as follow:

```
var raw_data = data.text;
var output = '<figure><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?image”></figure>';
parsedHTML = raw_data.replace(/\[gallery\]/ig, output);
$('article').html(parsedHTML);
```

Now I want to be able to get the html tags before and after [gallery].
So to be clear in this example, the code should retrieve the paragraph tag `<p>` and `</p>` :

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam convallis quam ac tristique imperdiet. **[gallery]** Mauris sit amet mi dignissim, lacinia odio non, porttitor est. Maecenas imperdiet quis sem quis elementum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.<p>
```

After it has the html tags, close the p before [gallery] and open a paragraph after it.
Look out for some advice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an HTML parser. Avoid regex for handling the HTML.

Comment: Will the outside tags always be `<p>` and `</p>`?  Or can they be any other tags?

Comment: Any tag. It should search for which tag is the first that will be find before and after the tag. @sideroxylon

Comment: With `$('figure').parent()[0].nodeName` you can find out the parent's tag. Knowing that, it should be easy to inject ending and starting tag before and after your gallery (the same way you replaced [gallery], if you wish, but as Quentin said, this does not look like the best practice)

Comment: You're just doing this wrong. Use dom manipulation methods (`document.createElement`, `new Text()`, `.insertBefore`, `appendChild`) and not regex replacent. Every time you alter inner HTML there's lot of calculation overhead associated with it.

Comment: Do you have a working example for me. That would be nice @TomášZato

Answer (score 1):

Or how about putting the P tags in there already?

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam convallis quam ac tristique imperdiet</p>
<div class="gallery"></div>
<p>Mauris sit amet mi dignissim, lacinia odio non, porttitor est. Maecenas imperdiet quis sem quis elementum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.<p>
```

And then for your jQuery:

```
var output = '<figure><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?image”></figure>';
$( "div.gallery" ).replaceWith( output );
```

Inserting tags into your DOM is asking for carnage later down the line, if they're already there you know how they're going to behave!

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has said, avoid a complicated regex solution.  If you are just looking to create a line break before and after the image, you could try something like this with basic string replacement.

```js
var input = 'IMAGE ID';

var str = '<p>blah blah blah [gallery] blah blah blah [gallery]</p>';

var output = str.replace(/\[gallery\]/g, '<br>' + input + '<br>');

$('#original').html(str);
$('#replaced').html(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "original"></div>
<div id = "replaced"></div>
```